# Is ～めぇし a possible typo?

Tags: translation, sentence-final-particles

Doing more reading in mangas and found `～めぇし`. Here is the sentence:

> ここは地獄じゃある**めぇし**! お前が死にそうな顔すんなよ！

I perceived this as "This isn't hell." Though, it confused me when saw **めぇし**. I always thought it was `まい` or meant to be `ねぇし`. Can someone clear this up?

Comment: I see... a famous line.  >>> ONE PIECEの質問です ONE PIECEで「ここが地獄じゃあるめェし」とだれかが言ってませんでした？？あの言葉が心に残ってるのですが載ってる巻数などが思い出せませんどこで・誰が・誰に向かって言ったか教えてください詳しく教えて... _________________________________ Also see:  何もあの人だけが
世界中でいちばん
 やさしい人だと
 かぎるわけじゃあるまいし

Comment: Aaah...I see you read One Piece as well. Are you a fan as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this `めぇ` isn't a typo.  It's a colloquial form of the negator `まい`, in which the vowel sequence /ai/ is replaced with the long vowel /eː/.  You'll hear this sort of change in all sorts of words, not just in `ない` → `ねぇ`.

The sentence `ここは地獄じゃあるまいし` means "It's not like this is hell".