# How to say:'It's not like he's dying or anything'?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

"別に死ぬあいつはわけじゃないし" 
I want this to convey a sense of denial

Comment: What's with the strange placement of あいつ?

Comment: That's why i tagged it as grammar as well

Comment: You could drop it or (given how the sentence seems like) you can use right dislocation and put it to the right ~じゃないし、あいつ(は). It's not a proper grammar but it's used in conversations

Comment: And the sentence as whole, does it say " It's not like he's dying or anything" or i get that wrong?

Comment: I think so, though lack of answers here makes me somewhat unsure, would think this would have been answered long ago

Comment: [「～～わけじゃあるまいし。」](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=URIWWpvkNMHz8QXoxb8Y&btnG=Search&q=%22%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%BE%E3%81%84%E3%81%97%22+%22It%27s+not+like%22&oq=AP+%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%80%80%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10892.12635.0.19575.5.3.0.0.0.0.494.585.1j4-1.2.0....0...1c.1j4.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.7mkBp0Wcs0g)を使ってみたら・・　Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38536/9831

Answer (score 1):

彼は別に死にかけて（い）るわけでもないし or maybe instead of the last し something like でしょう or some more colloquial form.

Comment: I assume the first し is 死? Can you please give some comment about reasons for differences from OP's sentence? (maybe outside dropping あいつ which was already pointed out)

Comment: Yes, it was　死　and I used the structure with 死にかける　since I interpreted the English original sentence to refer to e.g a situation where someone is sick / has been hurt, but the situation is not directly life-threatening, i.e. meaning similar to "he is not about to die". (We well all die eventually anyway).  How to end the sentence depends on what is meant by "denial" and if there is a sense of actual worry. し would be a good choice when the person is confident that there will be no fatality, while でしょう would be good if the person is actually worrying  and  wants to hear some reassuring words.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think では would be also ok or should be でも? Somehow this もfeels more like "also" to me which wouldn't fit, but maybe it's just intensifier, or is it necessary? Also I wonder why the downvote (wasn't me), seems correct to the limit of my knowledge, so I guess I'll upvote it

Comment: では should also work, but I put も to bring the meaning of the original "or anything". In that way, I think it actually is pretty close to "also", if we think if the "or anything" as an addition that in a way "extends" the meaning of the "dying" to something like "not only dying, but also not being close to dying"

Comment: the 彼は feels a bit weird, also the かけている. I take it more as the guy does something stupid whereas someone reassures (aka, is in denial), "no problem, he won't die or anything". Personally I guess I would just say something like 別に死にはせん (with an appropriate ending)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably say 「あいつ、"死にそう／かけてる"とか、それほど"ヤバい／ヒドい"ってわけじゃないでしょう?」.